# Opening a new child form while in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I am trying to open a new child form (BuyNow Form) when a thread exits and I determined license type to be expired. During a thread, I open a new process that does the license calculation and sends the information back to the Main process. The problem is, thread gets exited before all the information is received so I can't open the BuyNow form, because it doesn't know the license is expired yet.

This is the code:

```
        BackgroundWorker BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        BW.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Process.Start("LicenseManager.exe", "-Check");
                // PSI Info, DataRecieved Event Args and etc.. included in Process.
                // Opens the process which takes about 5 second to calculate and post
                // license information. Then LicenseMode changes to TrialExpired
                // if not activated and trial expired.
            };
        BW.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // This never gets executed because License is not changed to TrialExpired by the time BW is completed.
                if (LicenseMode == License.TrialExpired)
                {
                   new BuyNowForm().Show();
                }
            };
        BW.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I tried to open the BuyNowForm while in a thread but that freezes the newly created form. I don't want to try Thread.Sleep and wait few extra seconds for the process to send information.  Thread.Join() seems to freeze the Main UI for few seconds. Process.Exited += does not work either, cuz the process was created in a thread so when it exits, BuyNowForm is still being created in a thread.

Anything you guys can think off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Process` class has a `WaitForExit` method. This will wait, surprise, until the process exits. You have to do that (obviously) in `DoWork`.

You should not open a form from another thread (which is true for `DoWork`). `RunWorkerCompleted` would be the correct way, because it is executed in main GUI thread.

Comment: Oh my god! I been over thinking this so much, I overlooked the simplest solution lol. Thank you so much for your help (: - Solved the problem. Will "Accept" in 10 minutes (requirement).

Comment: Just to update, I could of also opened it by invoking it. That would of fixed the freezing error.